# IsInRole Works only when user sign in

Tags: asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, asp.net-roles

Why HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Customer") returns false if the user is not logged in, I think because user is considered anonymous is this case, Correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Anonymous users cannot belong to a role.

Notice that the `User` object for an anonymous user is a `GenericPrincipal` and while it implements `IPrincipal`, the `IsUserInRole` method always returns false because there are no roles supplied when it is created by `FormsAuthenticationModule`.

Also notice that the `User` object for an authenticated user is a `RolePrincipal`, which queries `RoleManager` in `IsUserInRole`.

Answer (score 0):

Until the user don't login to your application, application behave it as an anonymous user and this user is no known for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior, the anonymous user has no roles.

But if it returns false you can't be sure the user is not authenticated (better use [User.Identity.IsAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated.aspx) property).